# It's possible to trigger react-qr-scanner in Cordova?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, react-qr-code

I'm trying to trigger the ReactJS QR Code Scanner using the "react-qr-scanner" Library, it's working perfectly fine in browser.

However, when I put it into a Cordova as a iOS/aOS Mobile Application, it would only show the blank page and having the following error message

```
"ERROR: {"name":"NoVideoInputDevicesError","message":"No video input devices found"}".
```

*The Camera Permission already enable for that mobile app

May I know how can I fix it. Thank you very much !!

Update 1:

I'm using the example code to trigger the QR Code Scanner
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-scanner

Comment: Can you post relevant code as to how you are triggering the QR scanner?

Comment: I'm using the example provided in "react-qr-scanner" to trigger the QR Scanner

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-scanner